# Page Number on Inserted PDF Page Not Shown

Tags: luatex, page-numbering, pdfpages

**Code**

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\paperheight-0.5\height}{%
      \makebox[0.92\paperwidth][r]{%
        \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}
      }
    }
  }
}
\includepdf[
  pages = -,
  landscape = true
]{inserted-page.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Question**

As can be seen on the screenshot, the page number is indeed typeset on the page, but it appears to be typeset in white (since I can't see it if I don't highlight it). What is wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

**Addendum**

I compile using `lualatex` if it is of any importance.

Also, I've used equivalent code for other inserted pages and there the page number is shown as I expect it to, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: make an educated guess, what BG means in the command name.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would guess "BG" = "background". Unfortunately I don't see how this gives a hint as to how I make the typed page number shown.

Comment: try with FG instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That does the trick. Thanks! I just don't understand why the `BG` version then works for me in other places, but nevermind.

Comment: well obviously your PDF has a white, opaque background.